# Removing top commits causes problems with other local repositories

Tags: git

I have a simple project with a lot of small commits. I would like to get rid of some of them. I am testing this right now on some test project. I have a folder that simulates a remote repository and two other folders that are connected to it, `test1` and `test2`. This is the state of remote and local repositories before I did anything:

```
* 0000002C  (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Small commmit 12
* 0000002B  Small commmit 11
* 0000002A  Small commmit 10
* 00000029  Small commmit 09
* 00000028  Small commmit 08
* 00000027  Small commmit 07
* 00000026  Small commmit 06
* 00000020  Big commmit 02
* 00000015  Small commmit 05
* 00000014  Small commmit 04
* 00000013  Small commmit 03
* 00000012  Small commmit 02
* 00000011  Small commmit 01
* 00000010  Big commit 01
```

I run `git reset --mixed` to get rid of a couple of small commits up to the first big one:

```
git checkout master
git reset --mixed 00000020
git add .
git commit -m "New starting"
git push --force origin master
```

Everything is ok. After force pushing, the remote repository has been updated and I have no longer all those small commits:

```
* 0000002D  (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) New starting
* 00000020  Big commmit 02
* 00000015  Small commmit 05
* 00000014  Small commmit 04
* 00000013  Small commmit 03
* 00000012  Small commmit 02
* 00000011  Small commmit 01
* 00000010  Big commit 01
```

In the other folder, I fetched for update and this is the log:

```
* 0000002D  (origin/master, origin/HEAD) New starting
| * 0000002C    (HEAD -> master) Small commmit 12
| * 0000002B    Small commmit 11
| * 0000002A    Small commmit 10
| * 00000029    Small commmit 09
| * 00000028    Small commmit 08
| * 00000027    Small commmit 07
| * 00000026    Small commmit 06
|/
* 00000020  Big commmit 02
* 00000015  Small commmit 05
* 00000014  Small commmit 04
* 00000013  Small commmit 03
* 00000012  Small commmit 02
* 00000011  Small commmit 01
* 00000010  Big commit 01
```

I don't know how to proceed. There is 0000002D commit `origin/master` from the other folder which I want to be most updated, and local master in two different branches. What do you think needs to be done right now to bring this local repository to be in the same state as the first folder? I tried `git rebase` and it failed. `git merge` creates a new commit and merge local `master` with `origin/master` which of course would be a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't force push. People who have already pulled your original changes will basically be confused as hell

Comment: I realised that. I have prepared this test to see what would happen. I am glad I haven't done it on live project :p

Comment: This is why you should create separate branches for new development, and even smaller branches for each new piece of development, and basically never, ever rewrite history on the main branches that multiple team members work off of.  Also a good idea to just keep the "small changes" that you are personally working on local, and only push if you need help from someone else or once you are done - because then you can rewrite the local changes to your heart's content, and push after the commits are the way you want (or just merge/rebase into the shared branches).

Comment: @LightCC Thanks for advice. I work at two different offices on different computers and sometimes from home. I push on daily bases. As for small branches, this is might work but people still can see my messy branches and what I have done. If I create my own branches and mess with them, it should not affect anyone else but me, is it correct?

Comment: Correct - as long as you are the only one working in them.  This, like anything having to do with branch management, is more to do with your working agreement with the team than anything else.  As long as people know not to build new things off your individual working branches, no harm, no foul.  Then you just need to make sure you commit whenever you are going to have to swap PCs so you can pick back up (of course). @Celdor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are confident that your second repository doesn't have any changes that aren't already in your first repository, run this in your second repository:

```
git fetch
git checkout -B master origin/master
```

This will force-reset your local version of `master` to be identical to `origin/master`.

For this scenario, it's important to understand "[the perils of rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing#_rebase_peril)", or in your case, resetting.

In short, whenever you rebase or reset code, you are re-writing your commit history. It is intuitive to think that you are editing the old commits, but you are actually taking the changes from old commits and creating new commits from them.

This means that before you updated your second repository, it still had all the original commits. When you updated it, it simply added on the new commit(s) you've created–in your case, "New starting", and merged everything.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about option -B of checkout.

Comment: @Celdor it's a personal favorite of mine. Enjoy! :)